# Find a value out of 3 java

Tags: java

I have seach in this site and have found some things that talk about this topic but can't seem to fix what I'm searching, I have tried and after some hours of seaching and of trial and error I decided to post the question since I can't find a way to do what I want to do. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class intermedio
{public static void main(String[] args) 
{InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
int a, b, c; 
int max, min, mid;
try
{
    System.out.println("first value");
    a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("second vaule");
    b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("third value");
    c = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if(a >= b && a >= c && b >= c)
    {
    max = a;
    mid = b;
    min = c;
    System.out.println("middle value is: " + mid);
    }else if(a <= b && a <= c && b <= c)
    {
    min = a;
    mid = b;
    max = c;
    System.out.println("middle value is: " + mid);
    }else if(a >= b && a <= c && b <= c)
    {
    mid = a;
    min = b;
    max = c;
    System.out.println("middle value is: " + mid);
    }else if(a >= b && a >= c && b <= c)
    {
    max = a;
    min = b;
    mid = c;
    System.out.println("middle value is: " + mid);
    }else if(a <= b && a <= c && b >= c)
    {
    min = a;
    max = b;
    mid = c;
    System.out.println("middle value is: " + mid);
    }else if(a <= b && a >= c && b >= c)
    {
    mid = a;
    max = b;
    min = c;
    System.out.println("middle value is: " + mid);
    }
}catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

I have test it with 1, 2 and 3 and it always gives me what I ask like if ask for the min it gives me 1, if I ask for the mid it always gives me 2 and if I ask for the max it gives me the 3. What I want my code to do is that instead of putting the `System.out.println("middle value is: " + mid);` at the end of each `if` I want to put the whole line at the end of my code. Basically what I want is a way to simplify my code.

Comment: What was the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want my code to do is that instead of putting the
>   System.out.println("middle value is: " + mid); at the end of each if I
>   want to put the whole line at the end of my code

So... just do that?  Take the line out of the multiple places it is now, and put it right after the last `else if` block.

If the compiler complains that it might not be initialized, perhaps you should initialize `mid` to 0 when you declare it.

Comment: Ok that part seems simple, but also is there a way to simplify that many `if` conditions to have fewer lines in the code and still get the answer of what value is `min`, `mid` or `max`?

Comment: Although you could rearrange the way you do the if statements to make the program do less work, it would probably not be fewer lines of code.  If `a <= b` and `b <= c` then you don't actually have to check whether `a <= c` - it has to be true.  And the last `else if` must be true if you got that far, so you could just make it `else`.  But no matter how you do it, there are six possible arrangements of a, b, and c.  You could nest the if statements, and then if `a<=b` and `a<=c` you know a is min before you check whether `b<=c`, but that would probably be *more* lines of code.